# A tensor-based Diffie-Hellman exchange

Tags: public-key, diffie-hellman, key-exchange

Below is a description of a "cube" Diffie-Hellman, based on commuting matrix actions on tensor products.  Some questions:

1. References for something similar?
2. Obvious flaws, is this a terrible idea?
3. Any other comments?

### Definitions

Let $S$ be a finite ring, $n$, $k$, positive integers, and $R=M_k(S)^n$ the $n$-fold product of $k\times k$ matrices over $S$.  Let $M$ be the $R$-module $(S^k)^{\otimes n}$, the $n$-fold tensor product of the free $S$-module of rank $k$.  $R$ acts diagonally on $M$ (say from the left).

[One could also let $k=k_i$ vary with the index $1\leq i\leq n$, but we fix $k$ for simplicity.]

### Cube Diffie-Hellman

Let $T\in M$ be fixed and public (perhaps of a particular form?).  Alice and Bob randomly choose $A, B\in R$ that commute (or commute with some probability).  Alice sends Bob $T_A=A\cdot T$ and Bob sends Alice $T_B=B\cdot T$.  Their shared key is
$$
T_{AB}=T_{BA}=A\cdot T_B=B\cdot T_A
$$
assuming $A$ and $B$ commute.

For instance, Alice could choose a random index $a$ and $A\in M_k(S)$ as the $a$th coordinate of $R$ (with $I_k$ in the other coordinates) and similarly Bob could choose a random index $b$ and $B\in M_k(S)$ as the $b$th coordinate of $R$.  Similar variations are possible, e.g. Alice acts on first half of coords, Bob acts on second half:
$$
T_A = (A_1,\ldots,A_{n/2},I_k,\ldots I_k)\cdot T, \quad T_B = (I_k,\ldots I_k,B_1,\ldots,B_{n/2},)\cdot T.
$$

### Is the action easy to compute?

If $T$ is a random tensor, then one has to go through all $k^n$ basis elements $e_{i_1}\otimes\cdots\otimes e_{i_n}$ (where $\{e_i\}_{i=1}^k$ is the standard basis for $S^k$), apply the coordinate maps (e.g. $A=(A_1,\ldots, A_n)\in R$) and simplify.  This is basically $nk^n$ replacements ($e_{i_j}\mapsto A_je_{i_j}$) and collecting coefficients to rewrite in the standard basis.

[This computation can be reduced if $T$ is taken to be, say, a "pure" tensor, $v_1\otimes\cdots\otimes v_n$ (now only $n$ replacements).  However, the final shared key computation will be large again.]

### Is the action hard to invert?

Problem:  Given $T$ and $X\cdot T= T_X$, find $X$.  When $n=2$, this is easy; just (pseudo)invert $T$.  For larger $n$ (say over a field), I think one can "reduce" $T$ to some standard form, e.g. compute $Y\in R$ s.t. $Y\cdot T=T_0$, with $T_0$ something like a higher-order identity tensor $\sum_ie_i\otimes\cdots\otimes e_i$.  If $X$ and $Y$ "mostly" commute then $X$ might be computable from $Y\cdot T_X$.